# Textual analysis with python - program stalls after 8 runs

Tags: python, nltk

I want to do a textual analysis of multiple text files (>50,000 files), some of which are in html script. My program (below) iterates over these files, opening each one in turn, analyzing the content with NLTK module and writing the output to a CSV file, before continuing the analysis with the second file.

The program runs fine for single files, but the loop almost stalls after the 8th run, even though the 9th file to analyse is no larger than the 8th. Eg. The first eight iterations took 10 minutes total, whereas the 9th took 45 minutes. The 10th took even longer than 45 minutes (file is much smaller than the first ones).

I am sure the program could be optimized further, as I am still relatively new to Python, but I don't understand why its becoming so slow after the 8th run? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
#import necessary modules
import urllib, csv, re, nltk
from string import punctuation
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import glob

#Define bags of words (There are more variable, ie word counts, that are calculated)
adaptability=['adaptability', 'flexibility']

csvfile=open("test.csv", "w", newline='', encoding='cp850', errors='replace')
writer=csv.writer(csvfile)
for filename in glob.glob('*.txt'):

    ###Open files and arrange them so that they are ready for pre-processing
    review=open(filename, encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore').read()
    soup=BeautifulSoup(review)
    text=soup.get_text()

    from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
    wnl=WordNetLemmatizer()

    adaptability_counts=[]
    adaptability_counter=0
    review_processed=text.lower().replace('\r',' ').replace('\t',' ').replace('\n',' ').replace('. ', ' ').replace(';',' ').replace(', ',' ')
    words=review_processed.split(' ')
    word_l1=[word for word in words if word not in stopset]
    word_l=[x for x in word_l1 if x != ""]
    word_count=len(word_l)
    for word in words:
       wnl.lemmatize(word)
       if word in adaptability:
         adaptability_counter=adaptability_counter+1
    adaptability_counts.append(adaptability_counter)

    #I then repeat the analysis with 2 subsections of the text files
    #(eg. calculate adaptability_counts for Part I only)

    output=zip(adaptability_counts)
    writer=csv.writer(open('test_10.csv','a',newline='', encoding='cp850', errors='replace'))
    writer.writerows(output)
    csvfile.flush()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're never closing the files once you open them. My guess is you are running out of memory and it's taking so long because your machine has to swap data from the page file (on disk). Instead of just calling `open()`, you either have to `close()` the file when you are finished with it or use the `with open` construct, which will close the file automatically when you are done. See this page for more information: http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm

If it were me, I would change this line:

```
review=open(filename, encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore').read()
```

to this:

```
with open(filename, encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as f:
    review = f.read()
    ...
```

and make sure you indent appropriately. The code you execute with the file open will need to be indented within the `with` block.

Comment: is there any downfall to explicitly closing a file that was opened using `with`

Comment: None that I am aware of. It closes after you exit the block, which is presumably when you're done using it.

Comment: Did you mean explicitly calling `close()` from a `with`?

Comment: Yes, from within the block itself. something like  `with open('tieline.txt', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.data)
        f.close()` which I am using somewhere

Comment: I mean, it's redundant... I'm not aware of any downfalls specifically. `close()` isn't necessary because `with open()` already handles that for you.

Comment: From the docs: "It is good practice to use the with keyword when dealing with file objects. This has the advantage that the file is properly closed after its suite finishes, even if an exception is raised on the way. It is also much shorter than writing equivalent try-finally blocks."

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects

Comment: Thanks! It makes sense. My computer is not cooperating right now, but I will test your suggestion and hope that it improves the run time.

Comment: context manager is always a good idea: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/ =)

Comment: Additional edit: The proposed solution works... somewhat. It improves marginally the run time, but not by much. A colleague suggested looking into arrays and CountVectorizer, so that will be my next step. Still, thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

Since the accepted answer hasn't quite solved your problem, here's a follow-up:

1. You have a list `adaptability` in which you look up each word in your inputs. **Never look up words in a list!** Replace the list with a set and you should see a huge improvement. (If you are using the list to count individual words, replace it with `collections.counter`, or the nltk's `FreqDist`.) If your `adaptability` list grows with each file you read (does it? was it supposed to?), this is *definitely* enough to cause your problem.
2. But there might be more than one culprit. You leave out a lot of your code, so there's no telling what you other data structures are growing with each file you see, or if that's intended. It's pretty clear that your code is "quadratic" and gets slower as your data gets bigger, not because of memory size but because you need more steps.

Don't bother switching to arrays and `CountVectorizer`, you'll just postpone the problem a little. Figure out how to process each file in constant time. If your algorithm doesn't require collecting words from more than one file, the quickest solution is to run it on each file separately (it's not hard to automate that).

Comment: Thanks! Your answer is very helpful. I thought that writing the results to the csv file before reinitiating the loop would clear up the memory of the variables, but I may be wrong; I will check this.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying, but writing out a variable doesn't affect its contents. Assigning something else to the same variable does (e.g., an empty list).